# LINQ - IEnumerable.Join on Anonymous Result Set in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I've long since built a way around this, but it still keeps bugging me... it doesnt help that my grasp of dynamic LINQ queries is still shakey.

For the example:

**Parent** has fields (**ParentKey, ParentField**)
**Child** has fields (**ChildKey, ParentKey, ChildField**)
**Pet** has fields (**PetKey, ChildKey, PetField**)

**Child** has a foreign key reference to **Parent** on **Child.ParentKey** = **Parent.ParentKey**
**Pet** has a foreign key reference to **Child** on **Pet.Childkey** = **Child.ChildKey**

Simple enough eh?

Lets say I have LINQ like this...

```
Dim Q = FROM p in DataContext.Parent _
Join c In DataContext.Child On c.ParentKey = p.ParentKey
```

Consider this a "base query" on which I will perform other filtering actions.
Now I want to join the **Pet** table like this:

```
Q = Q.Join(DataContext.Pet, _
Function(a) a.c.ChildKey, _
Function(p As Pet) p.ChildKey, _
Function(a, p As Pet) p.ChildKey = a.c.ChildKey)
```

The above Join call doesnt work. I sort of understand why it doesnt work, but hopefully it'll show you how I tried to accomplish this task.

After all this was done I would have appended a Select to finish the job.

Any ideas on a better way to do this? I tried it with the PredicateBuilder with little success. I might not know how to use it right but it felt like it wasnt gonna handle the joining.

Comment: Wait a minute! Didn't you omit `Select` at the end of the first query?

Comment: Hah, yes I did. Regardless of the path taken in the code, there would always be a Q.Select(predicate) before the variable was used.

Funny lookin I suppose. Possibly a bad idea. Always worked in the app tho.

Comment: OMG.  Linq is so ugly in VB it's not even funny.  It's actually kind of sad.

Comment: @Dave, I agree with you regarding the *extension method* syntax, but the *query* syntax is almost the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to avoid leaving this unanswered, heres my workaround.

The Join didnt work because the compiler throws a piffy message saying that in that in the last part of the join, either both parameters must be strongly typed, or anonymous.

```
Function(a, p As Pet) p.ChildKey = a.c.ChildKey)
```

Naturally this isnt going to be the case, as my previous query is anonymous, and I'm trying to join it to a typed LINQ class.

I cant just change the type of the variable receiving the query either, because then I can only join on the type that I'm selecting. Like, if I wanna select the Parent based on the pet, then I can only perform my join this way if I'm joining the pet directly to the parent(to my knowledge at least), which can't happen as I have to go through the child to get to the pet.

My solution, was to re-query the same variable, and join on the strong type within the anonymous type.

```
Dim q = From anon in q _ 
Join p In DataContext.Pet On p.ChildKey = anon.c.ChildKey
```

That way, I can select the parent based on the pet by appending my where like this:

```
q = q.Where(Function(v) v.p.PetField = "Fido"
```

Then the select like this:

```
q = q.Select(Function(v) v.anon.p)
```

Ugly right? But it does work.